# Performance issue while trying to use gradient for realtime plot

Tags: ios, performance, core-graphics

I need to build a realtime plot sin(x)

So I update it 25 times per second. I try to use gradient for the plot line to make it transparent in the end:

Everything looks good - but the performance is critically low.. When I not creating gradient - everything works good.

The needed plot looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to improve my code to solve the performance issue?

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGFloat value;

UIBezierPath *graph = [UIBezierPath new];

for (NSUInteger counter = 0; counter < historyArray.count; counter++) {
    value = [historyArray[counter] floatValue];
    if (counter == 0) {
        [graph moveToPoint:CGPointMake((CGFloat) (bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width * 0.75 / 40), (CGFloat) (bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height / 2 - value * bounds.size.height / 2.1))];
    } else {
        [graph addLineToPoint:CGPointMake((CGFloat) (bounds.origin.x + (float) counter / (float) (40 - 1) * bounds.size.width * 0.75), (CGFloat) (bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height / 2 - value * bounds.size.height / 2.1))];
    }
}

if (historyArray.count > 0) {

    CGFloat colors[] = {
            0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
            0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0
    };

    CGColorSpaceRef baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, colors, NULL, 3);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace), baseSpace = NULL;

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.f);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);

    CGContextAddPath(context, graph.CGPath);
    CGContextReplacePathWithStrokedPath(context);
    CGContextClip(context);

    // Define the start and end points for the gradient
    // This determines the direction in which the gradient is drawn
    CGPoint startPoint = bounds.origin;
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width, bounds.origin.y);

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient), gradient = NULL;
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating the gradient isn't likely to be the performance problem. It's more likely clipping it to a complex path. It's not totally clear from your code how many line segments your path has, but I suspect it's in the hundreds, right?

As for more-performant ways to do this:

- Reduce the number of points in the path - if you're plotting points every X pixels horizontally, then you're plotting more than you need when the curve isn't changing much (near the peaks and troughs).
- Do away with the gradient altogether, and just draw your path with multiple differently-colored line segments. This might actually end up looking better, anyway, since you can adjust the transparency by distance traveled, rather than by horizontal coordinate.
- If you really do want the horizontal gradient, try applying it to subsets of the path, which might be faster than doing it all at once.

Comment: It is just about 40 points on my plot and I just want to get realtime sin(x) plot. Thx for your suggestions - I'll try to implement them